# Bridge Responders Jump shows a preempt or points...Playing Standard American

Tags: bridge

I am back, played a club level tournament recently.  Got creamed in it.  I think I couldn't deal with the pressure.  MY question is that my partner (an old timer) to my opening bid of 1 Club responded 2 Diamonds.  I thought it was a sort of a preempt bid but she had 14-15 points and 5 diamonds.  She was trying to say show a big hand which I failed to comprehend.  Needless to say we missed game.

as always many thanks for your time.

Comment: Please separate this question into two questions, as the answers to the two questions will be quite different!

Comment: Count; count; and count some more. The two most effective techniques at improving your game are: To count more; and to again discuss with partner which sequences are forcing and which ones are not. Weak players constantly distinguish themselves by not doing either task, and instead learning still more conventional calls that occur only rarely, and which they will use poorly from not having discussed the forcing and non-forcing continuations.

Comment: Just Did...thanks.  And you are absolutely right,  I am now taking a break from the conventions and focusing on table play and count.  Once this is in place will start work on bidding again.

Comment: Since you seem to have a regular partner, you may want to discuss with him/her what your pair is going to play. It is meaningless to learn some biddings just to have partner totally disagree with your methods and methodology.

Answer (score 4):

For questions about Standard American, you can always refer to the  [Standard American Yellow Card System Booklet](http://web2.acbl.org/documentlibrary/play/SP3%20(bk)%20single%20pages.pdf).

In this case, the booklet says that jump-shift responses are strong and slam invitational. The downside to the booklet is that it doesn't really cover followups for most bids.

Preemptive jump-shifts are quite popular among players who play a 2/1 system, but Standard American's inability to force to game at a low level makes slam exploration too difficult when responder holds a good hand with an excellent suit unless you play strong jump-shifts.

Answer (score 1):

Neither a "jump shift" nor a "jump raise" are pre-emptive.

Since your partner's bid was in a new suit, and "one more than necessary," it was a "jump shift" that showed more than a minimum opening hand; at least 15-16 high card points. Opposite a minimum opening hand, it is good for a minor suit game if you can find a fit. If you similarly have a "more than a minimum opening" with at least 15-16, the two of you are close to the slam zone with a minimum of 30-32. Then the viability of a slam depends on "extras" such as "controls," short and long suits,  extra trumps (above eight), or extra strength (above 15-16) in at least one hand.

A "jump raise" from one to three *clubs* is a "limit raise" showing just below a minimum opening hand, say 10-12 points. Opposite a minimum opening hand, it means that you and partner have at least 22-24 points so it is not predominantly pre-emptive. It does, however have some pre-emptive value, insofar as it prevents opponents from "reopening" a higher ranked suit with 17 points between them at the one or two level.